# Is it safe to have a datetime column as foreign key in a table?

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, database

I have two tables. Table A and B. Table A has a column with auto increment as primary key.

```
id    name       date_created
1     Kletian    12-12-12 12:12:12  
2     Vormav     12-12-12 12:12:13
3     Agrias     12-12-12 12:12:14
4     Ramza      12-12-12 12:12:15
```

Table B should has a foreign key referencing the id in table A. But since the id is auto increment (generated by mysql) I can't assign it using server side programming (I use PHP to insert). But, In table A, there is a column date_created with datetime attribute.

Normally, this is the table B should looks like:

```
id     images
1      abc.jpg
1      def.png
1      ghi.jpg
2      jkl.png
3      mno.jpeg
3      pqr.png
```

and this is my plan for table B:

```
date_created           images
12-12-12 12:12:12      abc.jpg
12-12-12 12:12:12      def.png
12-12-12 12:12:12 
12-12-12 12:12:13
12-12-12 12:12:14       
12-12-12 12:12:14      pqr.png
```

Note:

- Getting the auto increment value via server side programming (PHP) is not reliable. Since user can delete a record and messed up the order.
- I have limited privilege to change the table structure. Minor changes is okay, but major changes is prohibited.
- Is my plan safe or there are another alternatives?

Comment: Table B should have another column that is the foreign key reference to table A if that is how you want to relate the data. I would not use a datetime for a foreign key reference.

Comment: What is a major change for your team? Setting a foreign key and changing the indexing on a table is a minor change? Would there be in your design more than one row with the same datetime in Table B? Also, don't get your first note. What order is messed up by deleting?

Comment: @Alfabravo no. only one date time (date_created) and several column  that will contain string/text.

Comment: @srayhunter any suggestions for me based on my table structure?

Answer (score 0):

**Sequence number:** Take one column in table **A** which you increment when new entry is inserted ( not auto-increment ) e.g:

```
seq_no | name 
  1    |  Kletian
  3    |  Agrias
```

So when you want to do new entry in a table **A**, just get the **`MAX()`** of **`seq_no`** and increment it by 1.

Also in table B, make **`seq_no`** as like a foreign key, as:

```
seq_no | images
  1    |  abc.jpg
  3    |  efg.jpg
```

Comment: Using max() is not safe when handling concurrency. If OP is worried about ordering, this won't work

Comment: well, I'll use ordering in the table. But, it seems worth to try.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you would want for your table DDL (schema):

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `table_a` (
  `id`                  MEDIUMINT   NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name`                TEXT        NOT NULL,
  `created_date`        TIMESTAMP   NOT NULL DEFAULT NOW(),
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `table_b` (
  `id`                  MEDIUMINT   NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `image`               TINYTEXT    NOT NULL,
  `created_date`        TIMESTAMP   NOT NULL DEFAULT NOW(),
  `table_a_id`          MEDIUMINT   NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  FOREIGN KEY (`table_a_id`) REFERENCES table_a(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

**Table B** will have a foreign key reference to **Table A**.

I am not sure if are able to make those changes, but that would be the ideal solution.

Comment: hmm.. i don't know. It seems there are many changes. Table A is created long before table B. adding one or two column is okay. I afraid there are anomalies. Great suggestion by the way.

Comment: @ashura91the big thing here is that you can create an foreign key to the table that is already created. You just need to add another column to Table B if it is already created. You can set the row null until the references are created.